# migrate project from Play Framework 1 to Grails

Tags: grails, playframework

is there a clean and easy method to migrate a project that was written for the playframework version 1 into grails?

I suppose I need to rewrite the whole project in grails . But I need Ideas on strategy and techniques to do minimal code rewrite as possible.

Comment: If you're ok with sharing your code with me, I'd be happy to help. It'd be good to have at least some docs on a migration process. Email me directly if you want.

Comment: Thank you. I have no problem sharing the code. I'll find your email and mail you. Thanks.

Comment: Please don't forget to post back here with what the final result is. Ideally a short version of the migration process with a link to a longer version of it.

Comment: I didn't received feedback from Mr. Birt. So this question remains open for anyone who has plans or ideas on how to do the play to grails migration.

Answer (score 0):

Both of them use MVC and Groovy. So there is not much adaptation on the code.

I think that the main changes you will have to do are:

- Separating the Querys from the Models of play and putting them on the Services of Grails.
- Rewriting the application and datasource configuration files.
- Url mapping.

It´s not much work compared to rewriting the whole project.

On the other side you should be cautious with the GORM and his database administration, because it´s way different to JPA.

**UPDATE!**

Just taken from a blog post.

> Plugins/Modules
>
> Grails: Grails has Grails plugins. They are simply amazing. And the
>   way they are organized on the site is also very good. It's very
>   important for me to see the grades. Unfortunately there are no reviews
>   - it would be helpful to read reviews about different plugins. I used at least two plugins - Spring security plugin and Searchable plugin.
>   Spring security worked like a charm although I had to spend some time
>   on adjusting it to the legacy database tables. The Searchable plugin
>   worked so-so. Whatever I did I couldn't customize the search results
>   (or maybe I didn't spend enough time?). I spent at least one evening
>   browsing the plugins directory and thinking "aha, I'll need this
>   plugin some time in the future. And this one too. And that!".
>
> Play: Play framework has a similar concept to plugins - modules. Some
>   of the functionality is already included in core Play and Play modules
>   are quite the same as plugins. Except - the modules directory doesn't
>   show grades or reviews so it's harder to make a choice - you are on
>   your own, take your own risk when choosing this or that module.
>
> Who wins: Grails

Here you have the original post.

Anyway I think that there are some more Grails plugins than Playframework modules. But this is just a thought and I didn't check it.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: there is also the problem of plugins. play uses its own plugins and we need a way to find a similar plugin in grails? what do you think about migration play plugins to grails issue?

Comment: hello, yes i think we need to find the grails equivalent plugin to the used play plugin. but this will require quit changes in configuration files and probably the classes using the plugins. brief a clean process to migrate from play to grails needs a carefull research .